# Overriding Backbone's URL function to Fetch Data From Local Store

Tags: javascript, caching, backbone.js

I am writing a caching system which works with backbone (which I am still new to).
The system is as follows:

First try to get the data from local storage and upon failing to do so then make the call to the server.

Can I overwrite the url() function to first check local storage and then make the call or should this mechanism be outside url() and backbone ? i.e. Maybe this is using backbone incorrectly ?

Thanks !

**Edit:**

As requested I am adding more details.

I am using backbone.js the specific library I am using via require.js is backbone_amd-min.

Code sample:

Model:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'cacher' ], function($, _, Backbone, cacher) {

    var article = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            title : '',
            content : '',
    },
    parse : function(response, xhr) {
        return response;
    },
    url : function() {
        //What I want to do is (specify where to retrieve the article):
        var articleInCache = cacher.inCache(this.flag);
        if(articleInCache)
            return localStorage
        else
            return remoteUrl;
    },
    flag : '2'
});

return article;
});
```

Can I modify url() or should I be modifying fetch()

Comment: Could you specify which libraries (Backbone version, Backbone.LocalStoarge version...) do you use and a sample of code?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question you first need a quick primer on `fetch`.  When you do:

```
someModel.fetch();
```

What happens behind the scenes is:

1. `fetch` uses the `url` (or `urlRoot`) method/property to figure out where to make the AJAX call
2. `fetch` uses the `sync` method to actually make the AJAX call.
3. After the AJAX call returns, `fetch` passes what it gets back through `parse`, then passes that to `set`.

Given that, you clearly don't want to override `url`, as it has nothing to do with the actual AJAX part that you want to replace.  You *could* override `fetch`, and that would work:

```
fetch: function() {
    var fetched = this.getLocalVersion();
    if (fetched) {
        return new $.Deferred().resolve();
    } else {
        return this.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
    }
 }
```

However, that won't help you when you want to `save` or `delete` your `Model`, so really `sync` (which covers all AJAX operations) is probably the ideal method to override.

... of course, there's no point in re-inventing the wheel, so rather than override anything your best bet is probably to use one of the existing Backbone LocalStorage libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried what you suggested and now I am getting some strange behaviour.

I do exactly your method says except that in the if block I say this.set(modelData) before the return.

The code works the first time but fails when I refresh the page. I.e. this.set(modelData) is not executed the 2nd time. 

Is there some additional processing in sync that I am unaware of ? Note: At this stage I am only trying to retrieve data from local storage.

Comment: It sounds like your `getLocalVersion` method isn't working, possibly because the data isn't getting stored elsewhere.  Are you doing something similar in your `save` method?  How exactly is your local storage working?

Comment: No I am not overriding save at all. I persist to local storage via calling an external library. Should I be overriding all these functions due to some backbone functionality hidden to me ?

Comment: No, you don't have to, but the important part is that you need to be saving your data in local storage in a way that your `getLocalVersion` method can retrieve.  If you're saying everything works until you refresh, that implies that the local storage data either isn't being stored or isn't being retrieved.